# Importing ng-bootstrap submodule includes entire ng-bootstrap in bundle

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-module

I am trying to switch from importing `NgbModule` to importing only the submodules I actually use, such as `NgbModalModule`.

```
import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

// ...      

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModalModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
```

However, the entire library remains in my final production bundle:

[image: Bundle analysis]

I have double checked that no references to the root module are left in my app module or any custom feature modules I import. (I am using Ivy)

What could be causes for this behavior?

EDIT: I've created a [minimal repo](https://github.com/MSkico/ng-bootstrap-bundle-test), showing the same behavior. There is nothing fancy whatsoever, just

- run `ng new`
- add `ng-bootstrap`
- import a submodule (`NgbPaginationModule`)
- run `ng build --prod` and bundle analyzer
- results in bundle including entire ng-bootstrap.js (442kB)

Comment: do you check your bundle stats in production build or in dev build?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2883

Comment: @Andrei It's a production build. I'm not sure I understand, but I don't lazy load any of the modules...?

Comment: `import('module')` with a round brace is a way to do lazy loading in js/ts. try to search it in your code

Comment: @Andrei no, i don't do any lazy loading. I tried a different approach. Instead of adding ngb via npm, I added the repo from guthub as a submodule and import the modules from the src folder. This works and does the job, though its not ideal and I would like to understand how it can be done with npm.